# Capybara's click_link and Rails controller actions - test is passing when it should not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am writing Capybara integration tests for my engine while developing.

I have an integration test to check that an account owner can actually delete a user. It uses the 'destroy' action of an Users Controller.

To my understanding, Capybara's default driver will do a GET when you click a link when you don't use a driver with javascript enabled so the 'destroy' action should not actually be called and the test should fail. In fact, I haven't even included the default rails javascripts at all yet.

However, my Capybara test which presses the delete link actually passes the test even though it fails as expected when I open a Chrome browser window and do the sequence manually.

User code:

**View: show.html.slim**

```
h2 User

= @user.to_yaml

= link_to 'Edit User',  edit_user_path(@user) if policy(@user).edit?
br
= link_to 'Delete User',  user_path(@user), method: :delete if policy(@user).destroy?
```

**Controller: users_controller.rb**

```
module Subscribe
  class Account::UsersController < Account::BaseController
    def index
      @users  = current_account.users
    end

    def show
      @user = current_account.users.find_by(id: params[:id])
      authorize @user
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
      @user.account_id = current_account.id # required for authorize
      authorize @user
    end

    def edit
      @user = current_account.users.find_by(id: params[:id])
      authorize @user
    end

    def update
      @user = current_account.users.find_by(id: params[:id])
      authorize @user

      do_new_sign_in = (current_user == @user)

      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        sign_in(@user, bypass: true) if  do_new_sign_in

        flash[:success] = "Update successful."
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      @user.account_id = current_account.id
      authorize @user

      if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "User successfully added."
        redirect_to users_path
      else
        flash.now["Sorry, could not create a new user. Please review the error messages."]
        render :new
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @user = current_account.users.find_by(id: params[:id])
      authorize @user

      @user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User successfully deleted."
      redirect_to users_path

    end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(
        :email,
        :password,
        :password_confirmation
      )
    end
  end
end
```

**Test: spec/features/users/sign_up_authorization.rb**

```
scenario "Can delete user" do
    click_link "#{user1.email}"

    click_link "Delete User"

    success_message = "User successfully eleted."
    expect(page).to have_content(success_message)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because these links are so common, the rack test driver has code ([see source](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rack_test/node.rb#L50)) to detect this and follow the link with the correct method.